# Echo image from folder together with database information

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, mysqli

I'm doing a tutorial where you save an uploaded image to a folder on your computer while saving information about who uploaded it, title of image and time of upload, to a database.

When someone enter the page with the uploaded image, a small text with information that is stored in the database, will appear right above the image(thumb sized). When you click on the thumbnail fancybox will kick in and you will get the original size of the image.

Though, my problem is that the image itself gets echoed each time someone uploads an image.

So if three people upload you get a total of 9 thumbnails. If 4 people upload it will be 16 images etc. They do not copy itself in the folder. Check screenshot please.
http://s122.photobucket.com/user/KcMello/media/Ska3080rmavbild2014-02-14kl110753_zpsc19caae9.png.html

What I need help with is, that if someone could check through the code below and tell me what im doing wrong. I think it's glob but im not sure.

Thanks!
yours sincerely,
Winterwind

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost","user1","test1","tutorial");
$selectall = "SELECT * FROM store";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $selectall);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $information =  ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date']; 

    echo "<strong>Titel: </strong>" . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Uppladdare: </strong>" . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Filnamn/bild: </strong>" . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Datum: </strong>" . $row['date'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    foreach(glob("bilder/thumb_*.jpg") as $filename){
        $original = substr($filename, 13);

        echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='massoravbilder' href='bilder/$original'> <img src='$filename' alt='$information' /></a>" . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Update of code:

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost","user1","test1","tutorial");
$selectall = "SELECT * FROM store";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $selectall);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $information =  ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date']; 

    echo "<strong>Titel: </strong>" . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Uppladdare: </strong>" . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Filnamn/bild: </strong>" . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Datum: </strong>" . $row['date'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    error_reporting(0);
    $original = substr($filename, 13);

    echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='massoravbilder' href='bilder/$original'> <img src='bilder/thumb_" . $row['filname'] . "' alt='$information' /></a>" . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The finished code:

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost","user1","test1","tutorial");
$selectall = "SELECT * FROM store";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $selectall);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $information =  ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date']; 

    echo "<strong>Titel: </strong>" . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Uppladdare: </strong>" . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Filnamn/bild: </strong>" . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Datum: </strong>" . $row['date'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    error_reporting(0);

    $original = $row['filname'];

    echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='massoravbilder' href='bilder/$original'> <img src='bilder/thumb_" . $row['filname'] . "' alt='$information' /></a>" . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Many thanks to Jojo for helping me out!:)

Comment: You show all jpg images starting with thumb_ in your bilder folder for each row in your database. You should probably name the images based on the row id in your database and then just show the corresponding image '<img src="bilder/thumb_'.$row['id'].'">' instead of looping throug all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you are showing all images in folder "bilder" where the name starts with "thumb_" without checking if the image actually belongs to the row from your database table. Assuming that your naming pattern for the thumbnails is like this:

```
bilder/thumb_ . $row['filename'] . '.jpg
```

You could update your code to something like this (untested):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$information =  ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date']; 



echo "<strong>Titel: </strong>" . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Uppladdare: </strong>" . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Filnamn/bild: </strong>" . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
echo "<strong>Datum: </strong>" . $row['date'] . "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='massoravbilder' href='bilder/$original'> <img src='bilder/thumb_" . $row['filename'] . "' alt='$information' /></a>" . "<br>";

}
```

A better idea IMO is to store the thumbnail-path in your database as well and use it to render your thumbnail-link.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! It works really good. The database information together with the alt function works very well.
But when I click on the image it sends me to the folder. Fancybox does not work anymore... Dont know what to do. Something with the searchway?
I updated my first post with the new code.

Comment: 2 things: 1. The $original variable is not set anymore, so the href of your link now points to "bilder/" only. I forgot to state that the code in my answer is completely untested ;) try to set $original = $row['filname']; before echo-ing the thumbnail. 2. If you get to see your folders contents when accessing the url "bilder/" it means you allowed directory listing on your server. This is ok for local machines, but a huge security issue for production servers. Please keep that in mind when finishing your software.